# Knockout Twitter Bootstrap double popover, delete item and close popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm new in KnockOut and now I`m trying very ambition thing, but without success.
I have multiple foreach. For 
the final Items I want to show popover when user click on it,
Thanks of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14837097/1732989)

```
//Bind Twitter Popover
ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {

 init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
     var tmplId = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
     var tmplHtml = $('#' + tmplId).html();
     var uuid = guid();
     var domId = "ko-bs-popover-" + uuid;
     var tmplDom = $('<div/>', {
         "class": "ko-popover",
         "id": domId,
         "data-bind": "withProperties: { label: '" + viewModel.label() + "', required: '" + viewModel.required() + "' }"
     }).html(tmplHtml);

     options = {
         content: tmplDom[0].outerHTML
     };

     // Need to copy this, otherwise all the popups end up with the value of the last item
     var popoverOptions = $.extend({}, ko.bindingHandlers.popover.options);
     popoverOptions.content = options.content;

     console.log($(element));
     console.log(element);

     $(element).bind('click', function () {
         $('.popover').hide();            
         $(this).popover(popoverOptions).popover('toggle');
         // If you apply this when the popup isn't visible, I think that it tries to bind to thewhole pageand throws an error
         if($('#' + domId).is(':visible'))
         {
             ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#' + domId)[0]);
         }
     });

 },
 options: {
     placement: "right",
     title: "",
     html: true,
     content: "",
     trigger: "manual"
 } };
```

It work almost perfectly.

1. The problem now is that I want to add the close button on the
   popover. My it`s not working. I also try with the additional JS function:

> $(document).on('click', "button.close.pull-right", function () {
>           $(".popover").hide();
>       });

But after closing the popover to see it again I must click twice.  And is it possible to remove the popover when user click outside of it?

2.And If I click on the other popover the first one is
    closing. In this way always will be visible only one. It`s almost working but after    closing the first one after that I must click twice to see it.

3.And the last thing is the Delete item button. Which again for me is not working. If Delete button is outside of the popover then I use :

> $parent.removeItem

And it's working

I already add this changes on the following Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/f2swC/1/
Which is a copy of the example on which I`m working

Any ideas how to fix my issues?

Answer (score 0):

For 1. & 2. I already write a solution.
It`s available here: http://jsfiddle.net/f2swC/9/

```
>         <div data-bind="foreach: items">
>             <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
>             <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: required" />
>             <button data-bind="popover: 'settingsPopover'">settings</button>
>             <br />
>         </div>
>         <script type="text/html" id="settingsPopover">
>             <h4> <span class="icon-cog"> &nbsp; </span> Attributes</h4> 
> <label> Label </label>
>             <input type="text" data-bind="value: label, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" /> ><label class = "checkbox" > 
><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: required" />
>Required
></label>
></br>
><a class="deleteItem" href="#" data-bind="click: >$root.removeItem">Delete</a>
></br>
><button class="close pull-right" type="button" data-dismiss="popover">close</button>
```

And JS

```
> function s4() {
>     return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
>         .toString(16)
>         .substring(1); };
> 
> function guid() {
>     return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4(); }
> 
> ko.bindingHandlers.withProperties = {
>     init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
>         // Make a modified binding context, with a extra properties, and apply it to descendant elements
>         var newProperties = valueAccessor(),
>             innerBindingContext = bindingContext.extend(newProperties);
>         ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerBindingContext, element);
>  
>         // Also tell KO *not* to bind the descendants itself, otherwise they will be bound twice
>         return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
>     } };
> 
> // Bind Twitter Popover ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
>     init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
>         var tmplId = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
>         var tmplHtml = $('#' + tmplId).html();
>         var uuid = guid();
>         var domId = "ko-bs-popover-" + uuid;
>         var tmplDom = $('<div/>', {
>             "class": "ko-popover",
>             "id": domId,
>             "data-bind": "withProperties: { label: '" + viewModel.label() + "', required: '" + viewModel.required() + "' }"
>         }).html(tmplHtml);
> 
>         options = {
>             content: tmplDom[0].outerHTML
>         };
> 
>         // Need to copy this, otherwise all the popups end up with the value of the last >item
>         var popoverOptions = $.extend({}, ko.bindingHandlers.popover.options);
>         popoverOptions.content = options.content;
> 
>         $(element).bind('click', function () {
>             $('.popover.fade.right.in').hide();   
>             $(this).popover(popoverOptions).popover('show');
>             // If you apply this when the popup isn't visible, I think that it tries to >bind to thewhole pageand throws an error
>             if($('#' + domId).is(':visible'))
>             {
>                 ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#' + domId)[0]);
>             }
>         });
>         
>     },
>     options: {
>         placement: "right",
>         title: "",
>         html: true,
>         content: "",
>         trigger: "manual"
>     } };
> 
> $('html').on('click', '[data-dismiss="popover"]', function (e) {
>     $('.popover.fade.right.in').hide(); });
> 
> 
> var ItemModel = function (data) {
>     var self = this;
>     self.label = ko.observable(data.label);
>     self.required = ko.observable(data.required); }
> 
> var ViewModel = function () {
>     var self = this;
>     self.initItems = [{
>         "label": "Item 1",
>         "required": false
>     }, {
>         "label": "Item 2",
>         "required": true
>     }, {
>         "label": "Item 3",
>         "required": false
>     }, {
>         "label": "Item 4",
>         "required": true
>     }, ];
> 
>     self.items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(self.initItems, function (item) {
>         return new ItemModel(item);
>     }));
>                       
>     self.removeItem = function(task) {
>             self.calendarItemArray.destroy(task)
>         };
> 
> };
> 
> $(function () {
>     var vm = new ViewModel();
>     ko.applyBindings(vm); });
```

But I`m still looking for a way to delete item from popover.

The problem is that I don't now how to call $parent from Popover HTML?

Comment: After last Edit of Fiddler I receive the $parent is not defined.(from html).